PREPARATION OF SALTS
A liquid turns white anhydrous copper sulfate blue and has a boiling point of 103°C.
Which could be the identity of the liquid?
A alcohol
B petrol
C salt solution
D pure water

Note that questions looking like homework/test/exam/lab tasks, posted without significant attempts to understand/resolve them, are explicitly off-topic on this site and will be closed.
// Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

If "alcohol" specifically means ethanol (ethyl alcohol) then it wouldn't boil at 103°C. Petrol is unlikely to dissolve any kind of salt. That leaves (C) and (D).
It is common knowledge that water boils at 100°C. Addition of salts increase the boiling temperature (how much depends on the concentration), so (C) is the best answer.
In the future, try to do your own homework (even if it requires rereading your textbook) instead of posting on Stack Exchange. You won't have that lifeline on any upcoming exam.
